# how to fix sending string with python socket after sending a file

Tags: python, sockets

i am trying to make a server and client which sends a file from client to server and the server saves it to hard then the server asks for another file and if the answer of client is yes then the client sends the second file then the server again saves it and if the client answer is no server close the socket when i run this code the first file is sent 
and received successfully but after that both of the server and the client freeze and nothing happens what is wrong with it and how can i fix it?

my server code:

```
import socket

host = 'localhost'

port = 4444

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5) 

(client, (ip, port))=s.accept()


while True:

    data = "".join(iter(lambda: client.recv(1), "\n"))

with open('filehere.txt', 'w') as file:



    for item in data:

        file.write("%s" % item)

    if not data: break


client.send("is there any other file?")

d = client.recv(2048)

if d == "yes":

    while True:

        data = "".join(iter(lambda: client.recv(1), "\n")

        with open('filehere1.txt', 'w') as file:

             for item in data:

                 file.write("%s" % item)

        if not data: break

        s.close()

else:

    s.close()
```

my client code:

```
import socket

host = 'locahost'

port = 4444

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host, port))


f = open('myfile.txt', 'rb')

l = f.read()

while True:

    for line in l:

        s.send(line)

    break

f.close()

d = s.recv(2048)

a = raw_input(d)


if a == "yes":

    s.send("yes")

    f = open('myfile1', 'rb')

    l = f.read()

    while True:

        for line in l:

            s.send(line)
        break

    f.close()

else:

    s.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you check `a == "yes"` on client side even when server is not sending "yes"

I think you can check `a == "is there any other file?"` insted

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: you are checking ```a === "yes"``` in client side, why?

Comment: because i want to make a server and client that if the client is asked by the server for another file and the answer of the client is 'yes' it sends another file to the server

Comment: Ok, but first tell me that replacing ```a == "yes"``` with my answer works or not ?

Comment: you mean instead of `a =="yes"` i write `a == "is there any other file"`?

Comment: Yes, ? Included in double quotes